# How can I find The Big Oh bounds for a summation with multiple variables?

Tags: algorithms, summation, asymptotics

I have this as a homework problem so I won't post the same thing. I'll just post what I need to know to move forward.

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n 10^i i^2
$$

I'd just like to know how to split this summation. whether we need to split it? or just work on the big oh bounds for each individually.

I just want to know how to proceed if two terms within a summation cannot be simplified any further and both are dependent on i.

Comment: What is the dot?

Comment: Sorry. That was a mistake. I have edited my question.

Comment: Another approach: The summand is monotone increasing in $i$, so the sum has the same asymptotic as the integral $\int_0^n 10^x x^2\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $n$ is a constant with respect to $i$, we can just bring it out of the summation:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n 10^in^2 = n^2\sum_{i=0}^n 10^i = n^2 \left( \frac{10^{n+1} - 1}{9} \right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Start from the fact that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^na^i=\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$. Now, differentiate both sides with regard to *a*, and then multiply with *a*. Then repeat the process once again.

Comment: Yes I read this somewhere. But can I differentiate that w.r.t a? Are there any condition/preconditions that I need to check before differentiating ?